# Adding data on Print functionality in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web page designed in MVC3. I want to add some data (a disclaimer text) at the bottom of the page on the print button click and then print the page. How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can do this using css.

- Create a div at the end of your page and give them a className `disclaimer`
- Create a stylesheet file for the normal view of your page and set the `display` attribute to `none`
- Create another css file called `print.css` and set the display attribute to `visible`

#### Sample

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
     <head>
    <body>

        <!--- your content --->

        <div class="disclaimer">Your disclaimer text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Your myCSSfile.css**

```
.disclaimer { display: none; }
```

**Your print.css**

```
.disclaimer { display: block; }
```

#### More Information

- [CSS Design: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CSS and print media style sheets to make the element visible for printing.

A basic tutorial about this can be seen here: [CSS Media Types Create Print-Friendly Pages](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm)